# How to implement the 'Account Sign-in' helper in Google dialogflow? Getting a 'The agent returned an empty TTS'

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I require Account linking for my chatbot and so I included the Account Sign-in helper as below -

```
const {dialogflow, SignIn} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
});

//I have an intent 'Get Signin' triggered by event 'actions_intent_SIGN_IN'

app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const email = conv.user.email;
    conv.ask(`I got your email as ${email}. What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to next?`);
  }
});
```

When invoking my app, I get a 'The agent returned an empty TTS' response. What changes do I need to make?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you setup account linking in your project settings in actions.google.com? https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity

Comment: Hey Jordi, I haven't exactly. This is my test application. I have selected Linking Type as 'OAuth & Google Sign In', Grant Type 'Implicit'. I am not sure what to provide under Authorization URL and Token URL. Could you help me out here?

Comment: I've added an answer, this should fix your current issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization and Token Url are part of an Oauth process. It requires you to have your own service with user accounts to verify the user. If you don't have this I recommend you to use [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in) instead, it is the easiest way of AccountLinking and should work out of the box. If you do need the OAuth sign-in, then I recommend you to [read up](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/) on how OAuth works, because that is where the Authorization and Token Url are for.

When you setup acccountlinking correctly, the empty TTS should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I was not getting the option of direct google sign in because I had selected ' No, I only want to allow account creation on my website' amateur mistake. I allowed the app to sign in with a gmail id but now I am getting an  Error: Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience when trying to invoke the app.

Comment: You need to add your client ID of your actions on Google project to your code. An example can be found in the first code example here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#start_the_authentication_flow